# Close window as soon as it opens

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using the facebook dialog feed to allow the user to post a message to their wall.

You must provide a redirect_url for the page to redirect to after it has submitted,
I want on the page it redirects to to have some code which simply closes the windows.

I tried using

`<html><head><title>Close</title></head><body onload="window.close();"></body></html>`
and
`<html><head><title>Close</title></head><body onload="self.close();"></body></html>`

but to no effect.

(note that my testing is simply me opening a new tab with this url, could that be the issue?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only close windows with javascript if they were opened with javascript.

Otherwise, try looking at this question: [How can I close a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window" prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-this)