# How to exit my PWA after sending data with Web Share Target?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, web-share

If I share a picture from Google Photos to my PWA (installed with Chrome on Android and using this code https://web.dev/web-share-target/), I arrive on my PWA page. How to go back automatically to Google Photo?
Backend is in PHP if that matters.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but have you tried redirecting from your service worker's `fetch` event handler to an HTML page that immediately uses [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54787080/385997) to close itself?

Something like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // ...process the incoming event.request body here...

  // Once you're done, respond with a redirect:
  event.respondWith(Response.redirect('/self-closing-page.html', 303));
});
```

And then your `/self-closing-page.html` web page would just close itself. That would (maybe?) leave you back in the original Android app.

Comment: Holy Moly, I didn't expected this one to work. Thanks so much! To recap for other people, I output `echo "PWA redirect...<script>window.open('','_self').close()</script>";` when my PHP page finished receiving the data. This close the webpage and go back to the previous screen (Google Photo in my example) almost instantly.