# Window.close() surprisingly works in many browsers when opened through anchor tag with target="_blank" - but why?

Tags: javascript, html

As many resources state, e.g. this SO post: [javascript close current window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306882/javascript-close-current-window) as well as [Mozilla's own documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close), it shouldn't be possible to close a window/new tab that **wasn't** opened by javascript through `window.open()`.

However, I've just experienced that this works perfectly when then new tab has been opened through an anchor tag with the attribute `target="_blank"` in all the mentioned browsers at the bottom - however, it didn't work in Mozilla Firefox when the `rel="noopener"` attribute were included (did work without, but as per Mozilla's documentation, don't leave it out for security reasons).

How come this is the case? Is the `target="_blank"` simply considered a script?

Below you can find 2 sample codes that you can copy/paste into HTML files and try out on your own computer.

**First file: open the new tab:**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="C:\Users\..{insert your own file path here to the sample code below}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Open new tab</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second file: the HTML that you open with above snippet - contains a button to close same tab:**

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="window.close();">Close me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This has also been tested on a live website and has been tested to work on the following browsers as well:

- Internet Explorer, version 11.1397.17763.0 (with "blocked script/activeX content" allowed)
- Chrome, version 85.0.4183.83
- Edge, version 85.0.564.44

As mentioned above, it didn't work in Mozilla Firefox when `rel="noopener"` was included.

Comment: I honestly don't find this at all surprising; an `<a target=_blank>` tag does essentially the exact same thing as `window.open()`. Also note that MDN is a wiki; if the text is erroneous, you can fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How come this is the case? Is the target="_blank" simply considered a script?

The MDN already links to the relevant specifications.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-window-close says the window can be closed, if it is `script-closable`, and links to the following definition of that,

> A browsing context is script-closable if it is an auxiliary browsing context that was created by a script (as opposed to by an action of the user), or if it is a top-level browsing context whose session history contains only one Document.

(https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#script-closable)

`target="_blank"` creates a top-level browing context, and as long as you don’t navigate anywhere inside the popup, it also has a one-document history … So it is allowed to be closed by script.