# Automatically close HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Php document where after executing a query it will need to close the page.

My problem is that I cannot close the page.

I tried using javascript `window.close();` but that does not work.

I also tried using simulated key press(that is using control + w to close the tab) but was unsuccessful in making it work.

Comment: Some windows cannot be closed, depending if they were opened by the `Window.open()` method or not. Was the window opened by a script? See the MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: Hi, `window.close()` or just `close()` have to work. Could you provide a piece of your code please?

Comment: echo '<script> window.close()</script>';

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Comment: As @insyri commented above, it won't work. The browser remember whether was opened from js or not

Comment: @AdrianZavis try, anyway this works.

Comment: What's your browser?

Comment: @AdrianZavis i tried in Brave Browser, Mozilla and Chrome

Comment: It does work, I don't understand why but it works, or why this is overcomplicated to do so. I used Chrome v94.0.4606.81 in the experiment and it works.

Comment: in any page you can open another page, with this script you open page inside page (??) , so you can close, cause this is a script oppened page.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered this from a another post.  [javascript close current window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306882/javascript-close-current-window)

`window.open('','_self').close()`