# Pop Up Form With Close Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I realise that to most this is perhaps a very simple query, but I'm relatively new to working with the design elements of an HTML form, so please bear with me.

I'm using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/test.php) form to allow the user to upload image files.

What I'd like to be able to do, is change the form to a pop window that appears in the centre of the page, but after reading many tutorials, I must admit to being non the wiser. I just wondered whether someone could perhaps please show me what I'd need to do to create this.

I'd also wondered whether it would be possible if someone could perhaps help me out a little please on the 'close form' function. I've added the 'close' functionality to my form, but it appears as a hyperlink, with a 'Warning Message' dialog box appearing upon selection. I'd like, if possible, for this to appear as normal text and without the 'Warning message'.

Any help would truly be appreciated.

Many thanks and Kind regards

Comment: The general format of StackOverflow questions is that you post some code that you've written, state a problem with it, and ask for how *you* can fix it. With response, this question however LOOKS more along the lines of 'write some code for me'

Comment: Please learn Javascript. It will take some time, but will be worth it.

Comment: This site is about _"here's what I have so far but I'm stuck"_, not, _"please write my code from scratch because I don't know what I'm doing"_.  With 190 rep, you should already know this.

Comment: All, apologies if I caused offence, this was certainly not my intention, nor was it just to sit and wait for someone to write to code for me!. Feedback taken on board for future reference. Kind regards

Comment: The problem is that since you did not provide anything substantial within your question, there would be no practical way for anyone to help, short of just writing the code for you.  Learn JavaScript, learn about jQuery, then you should be able to easily implement your modal dialog box, or at least have something more solid for writing a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into a jquery lightbox type solution.  Using javascript the way you are the warnings and possible blocking of your popup could occur.  Here is a simple window.open article that will get your window opened

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Here is an article to close the window without getting a prompt:

[How can I close a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window" prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment [JQuery Dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). It's easy to implement even for a novice JQuery/Javascript developer

Comment: He does not even know he's supposed to use JavaScript and you throw jQuery at him.

Comment: From his [page](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/test.php) it looks like he has a backgroud in Javascript.

Comment: Yet his question did not mention JavaScript or even contain a "javascript" tag; I added that.

Comment: Hi, I started using HTML, Javascript and the rest about 8 months ago, and it's quite a steep learning curve. All I wanted, and it's perhpas my own fault as I put it rather badly, is someone who with a greater knowledge could offer some suggestions as the options available. Many thanks all and kind regards

Comment: JQuery learning curve is not that hard, it's good to have solid javascript background, but you can start using it even with limited javascript background.