# Not able to close current tab in ie7 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have tried many thigs as

`window.close(), 
self.close(),
var win = window.open("","_self"); win.close();`

also tried

function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}

But finally i did not get solution for this one , as it is our client requirement we have to do it any way , please suggest if any other possible way is there.

Comment: is it child window dat u r trying to close?

Comment: i just want to close tab in which application is open .

Comment: check links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

i used

window.parent.close(),

and it is working fine now.

but i don want any alert message while closing tab.