# Is It possible to close window without the alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we open a form in a new window, we would like to click a button to close the window without alert box.

Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks alot

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about `window.open()` function then just try to use `window.close()`