# How to close browser window in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a login form that is popped up as a separate browser window.  Once the API validates that the user is logged in, how do I close that login browser window in AngularJS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `$window.close()` in [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window) service.
You can broadcast the result to another controller like this [AngularJS – Communicating Between Controllers](http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/)

Comment: in angular modal bootstrap. it says :"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Comment: Silvio try use this style of injection:

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$window, $modalInstance) {
...
}

instead of

.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', ''$window', function($scope, $window, $modalInstance) {
...
}]);

Comment: Please have a look on this thread :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367921/close-window-in-angularjs-on-specific-url-angularjs/34368304#34368304

Comment: Hello dohaivu , can you please tell me that is there any way to track url of window, so that i can close the window on that specific url.

Answer (score 3):

This will first prompt the user, asking them whether they want to close their browser:

```
$window.close()
```

You'll want to inject the `$window` service into your controller/service. You can also use the global javascript variable [window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi) directly, but I prefer to do it the "angular" way and only use injectables.

Comment: @ChrisMontgomery this function is not working any more . It gives an error in Chrome "$window.close is not a function"

Comment: newWindow.close() worked for me in Chrome 52 when newWindow was a reference to a new tab/window that I had opened with: var newWindow = $window.open();