# Angular2 router.navigate opens the new page. How can i use window.close on opened route

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, routes

I am using the angular2.

I am on the page say `http://example.com/home`

When clicking on any link on the page, I am redirected to a new route, suppose, `http://example.com/customer`.  If I call the `window.close();` 
on this page its not allowing me to close the browser URL.

Could anybody can help on this?

**I am not opening new window or child window. I am just changing the route from one page to another page. Like firstly i am on page /home then redirected to new page /customer. Also i am on the same browser tab. If I call window.close(); on /home then it works for me, but not on /customer.**

Comment: I believe this post can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041484/how-to-close-browser-window-in-angularjs

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not help me. I am not opening new window or child window. I am just changing the route from one page to another page. Like firstly i am on page /home then redirected to new page /customer. Also i am on the same browser tab. If I call window.close(); on /home then it works for me, but not on /customer.