# close window when download finish-ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have this function made to save a PDF file in the local disk.

How do I automatically close the window after the download completed with an alert/msg box stating that the window will close?

This doesn't work:

```
Response.Write ("<script>alert('Save Finished'); self.close();</script>")
```

TheCode:

```
Private Function SaveLocal1(ByRef cnCon, ByVal PDFFile)
    Dim ObjStream
    Dim ObjFileSys
    Dim Size
    Dim fpath
    Dim bdata

    'Response.Write("<script>alert('local');</script>")

    fpath = "C:\1.pdf" 'path of the file in the local server
    filename = "LocalSave.pdf"     'name to be saved
        'Response.Write("<script>alert('file paths');</script>")

    Set ObjStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ObjStream.Open
    ObjStream.Type = 1
    ObjStream.LoadFromFile fpath
        'Response.Write("<script>alert('server.createobject');</script>")

    Response.buffer = TRUE
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="& filename & ";"
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

    Set ObjFileSys =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Size = ObjFileSys.GetFile(fpath).Size

    bdata = ObjStream.Read(Size)

    Response.BinaryWrite(bdata)     'the file will be saved in the downloads folder

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Save to local finish');</script>")
    ObjStream.Close
    Set ObjStream = Nothing    

    Response.Flush
    Response.End
    Response.Write ("<script>alert('Save Finished'); self.close();</script>")
End Function
```

Comment: did you have a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi, it describes how to close a window via Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose there are could be 2 issue in your code.

2nd issue:

```
Response.End
Response.Write ("<script>alert('Save Finished'); self.close();</script>")
```

Response.End -- is last command. That is all. "Document" completed.

> The End method causes the Web server to stop processing the script and
>   return the current result. The remaining contents of the file are not
>   processed.

Change order of following comand to

```
Response.Write ("<script>alert('Save Finished'); self.close();</script>")
Response.End
```

Comment: haha, I didn't note the Response.End before the Response.Write, good one!

Comment: Is there a way to force IE to close the tab without asking user's permission?

Answer (score 0):

Use response.redirect and send this page to another page, use window.close on body onload