# Close Browser without Prompt

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to close browsers, using JavaScript, PHP, or HTML without a prompt?

I was using this answer:
[How can I close a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window" prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)

I was using Internet Explorer but it has since been updated to version 10 (soon to be updated to 11) and this exploit does not work.

If there is a solution in a different (but updated) browser, that could work as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do this? As the current answer says, in general, a page that does this is incredibly rude, and I'm very happy that browsers don't allow it. But perhaps you have a good reason, and depending on that reason, another approach may work very well for you.

Comment: @hvd: Ever seen those "Close Window" buttons? It would be kinda ridiculous for them to ask you to confirm.

Comment: @Mehrdad I've only seen them in pop-up windows where the browsers already don't ask for confirmation. If that were what the OP wanted to use it for, we wouldn't be reading this question.

Answer (score 12):

- HTML can't do anything programatic. It's just markup.
- PHP can only do programatic stuff at your server, not the browser, so
  no solution there either.
- Finally, you cannot do it in JS either (unless it's a window opened
  by a script).

Imagine visiting a web site that closed your browser and you lost all of your open tabs.

Comment: Figured I couldn't do it in PHP and HTML, but thought I'd ask for the hell of it. The JS makes sense as well. Are there no other alternatives to close a browser programmatically?

Comment: Or even just close the tab - which invalidates your last point?

Comment: "Can't do it in JS"? That's not right - there are browsers where it can be done. If there's a spec that says it can't be done, please quote it.

Comment: I believe you can close a tab with js.  You can also write a js extension to many browsers which will allow this.

Comment: @Marcin: The spec you requested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close  And the MS one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536367(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are different hacks for different browsers. This code is based on the one [here](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/12/closing-window-without-prompt-in.html) with a small adjustment to the last `else` block to work on IE 11. I suggest you test it on other IE versions and see if it needs more tweaking.

```
function closeWindow() {
    var Browser = navigator.appName;
    var indexB = Browser.indexOf('Explorer');

    if (indexB > 0) {
        var indexV = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') + 5;
        var Version = navigator.userAgent.substring(indexV, indexV + 1);

        if (Version >= 7) {
            window.open('', '_self', '');
            window.close();
        }
        else if (Version == 6) {
            window.opener = null;
            window.close();
        }
        else {
            window.opener = '';
            window.close();
        }

    }
    else {
        window.open('', '_self', '');
        window.close();
    }
}
```