# To auto close a browser window after popping up new email message

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have a simple html that will pop out a new email message for people to send out email.
I need to close a window after the email message popped out. I wish to keep only the email message box.

This is my code, but it's not working:

```
<html>
       <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        function mymessage()
        {
         location.href = "mailto:abc@com.sg?subject=EmailToEnter";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="mymessage()">
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        settimeout('self.close()',1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried `window.setTimeout()`? - case sensitive, if i write settimeout it never works

Comment: You have more details here but this is a hack and it will be difficult for you to make it work cross browser.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi Closing the browser page on somebody is like throwing a customer out of your store with a kick in the ... Are you sure you need to do it?

Comment: Do you open window to send e-mail in the same window where javascript place? If it is, your script never been working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function mymessage()
{
    var d=document.createElement('A');
    d.target='_blank';
    d.href='mailto:abc@com.sg?subject=EmailToEnter';
    d.click();
}

function closewindow()
{
    var d=document.createElement('A');
    d.href="javascript:window.open('', '_self', '').close()";
    d.click();
}
```

Or you can use `window.open`

Also use construction like this

```
window.setTimeout(function(){closewindow();},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

setTimeout("window.close()", 1000);

BUT

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close