# Button Close Browser from Index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Am I really not able to have an Exit button to close out of all browsers? I have tried `window.close()` , `self.close()` and many more ways found all over the internet. They only work in IE which seems to be disappearing since Edge mode is coming out... Firefox and chrome act like the code does not even exist when it runs. Has anyone came across another method of closing with an exit button?

I have an index page with an exit button that I would like to automatically close the browser if chosen. Since it is my index page I do not have a window.open() command so it looks like window.close() is not an option?

Any ideas or suggestions of how to make my exit button close out the webapp?

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="Exit" value="EXIT">
```

I am just hoping this issue has been resolved since I cannot find it on the web but have seen posts since 2004...

Comment: Please see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)

Comment: What is the use case for wanting to force the browser closed? As a user, it would anger me to no end if a web site tried to close my browser.

Comment: Well its an internal web app and they want it exactly the same as there old one

Comment: which has an exit button the closes out of the app

Comment: I found this on the link from @hjardine window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();

Comment: but it still only works in IE and not firefox :/

Comment: Think it should work in Chrome etc.. just not Firefox apparently

Comment: @Vicki This answer looks good [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16412945/5118056)

Comment: Tested a few of the methods in that ^ link and they didn't work with Firefox and Chrome. Tell them that the close button is the red X in the top right corner.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still the case, but several years ago I learned that a browser window could only be closed by javascript if it was in fact opened by javascript.

Comment: yea that's all I kept finding going back since 2004, I was hoping there would of been a solution or work around since people have been trying since then =/ but since no one is jumping on this question I am guessing its still the same answer

Comment: @hjardine I get it to work in IE but I was hoping for FireFox specifically

Comment: well all browsers that is but firefox and chrome are the main ones im having trouble with

Comment: sorry @DanBracuk I added coldfusion tag incase that language had something written into it to do what I wanted since I am using CF also