# Window.Close() following a Mailto Javascript call not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, email, mailto

I have a JSP page that pops in a new window from an application I am working on, retrieves email information, along with other data and constructs some email meta data. The code then triggers a basic mailto: call which pops up local mail client. The page that calls the mail client is supposed to close via a basic window.close but it remains open after the mail client is launched. The same code works in Firefox/Chrome. Ive stripped out all the JSP code but the below is the basis of the page, and the same issue occurs with this lightweight version.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<div class='PagePanel'>
    <a id="SendEmail" href="mailto:test@test.com"></a>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        document.getElementById('SendEmail').click();
    </script>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        // automatically close the newly launched browser window     displaying this page as no widgets are painted on this page
        window.close();
    </script>

</div>

</html>
```

Any one know why the page doesn't close in IE9? (IE9 support needed) Closes in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi

Comment: Nothing in the console Jaromanda X.

Comment: Muhammad - that didn't work. I found that post earlier today and already tried it.