# Wait/sleep before window.close()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to set up a simple logoff-page which should close after 3 seconds.

Regarding this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)  is it possible to wait before that action?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sleep(3000);
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
</script>
```

With the sleep nothing happens at all.

**Edit:**

The solution of @Sidius works well in IE without a prompt.

Unfortunately Firefox blocks the Script:

> Scripts can not close any windows that were not opened by the script

Comment: `window.setTimeout(function(){},time);`?

Comment: Are you saying that the new window opens, it waits 3 seconds and then closes?

Comment: Does that hack to close a browser you did not open really still work?

Comment: @www139 nothing happens.

Comment: Check my edited answer @BlueFox

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
setTimeout(function(){
   window.close(); 
}, 3000);
```

Edit:
I think firefox might be a little more strict with the

```
window.open()
```

function. 
You might want to give values to the function's constructor.

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace);
```

In example:

```
window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
```

Comment: Your edit gets blocked as well. I guess this is due to the Firefox security options in our company.

Comment: See this link here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

If this also doesn't work, you will be definitely right. @BlueFox

Answer (score 2):

> You can use setTimeout() API to achieve the same -

```
setTimeout(window.close,3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.setTimeout()`:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
// Add this instead.
setTimeout(function(){
   window.close(); 
}, 3000);
```