# Closing the web browser not a tab which was opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to close the complete browser windows instead of closing a particular tab which I have opened.

I am able to close the tab which I have opened using javascript, but need to close the complete window.

Comment: No. Even if this were possible you should not do it, for the same reason that turning off your TV should not turn off your refrigerator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I close a browser window without receiving the "Do you want to close this window" prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854/how-can-i-close-a-browser-window-without-receiving-the-do-you-want-to-close-thi)

Comment: Why do you have that requirement? What scenario would validate your web application closing a user's entire browser? You might close down their internet banking, social, whatever.  
In short: you don't

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to close the entire browser via JavaScript